# Matching capitals and underscores between curly brackets

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract patterns like `{THIS_PATTERN}` from something like the following:

```
.intro-header {
    padding-top: 50px; /* If you're making other pages, make sure there is 50px of padding to make sure the navbar doesn't overlap content! */
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background: url(../img/{BG_IMAGE_0}) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

In this case it would be `{BG_IMAGE_0}`.

I can't figure out what's wrong with my regex: `\{[A-Z_]*\}`

I have a regex101 fiddle here:
https://regex101.com/r/KF5Sz6/2

Comment: You missed the "digit" `\{[A-Z_\d]*\}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
\{[A-Z_0-9]*?\}
```

You didn't seem to take into consideration the "0".

By doing it like so `*?`, you also make it non-greedy, which should prevent interference from other `{` `}`, on the same line, were you to stumble upon any in your future projects.

Comment: You don't need to escape brackets ( { and } ), you can also use \w instead of [A-Z_0-9]

Comment: You're right, I actually tried to keep it as close to the OP code as possible, assuming there might be other constrains that weren't mentionned, like only upper case letters, numbers and _. But `{\w+?}` would've worked just fine.